# ajaxを使った簡易掲示板、insertがうまくいかない

Tags: php, ajax

textareaに書いた内容ではなく、１がinsertされます。
原因がわからないので、教えていただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

---

index.php

```php
<div id="content">
    <div style="text-align: right"><a href="logout.php">ログアウト</a></div>
    <form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" id="form">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="70" rows="15" placeholder="メモを残してください"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="書き込む" id="write">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQueryライブラリの読み込み-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
//メッセージ用
    $(function(){
            //button click
            $('#write').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'index_do.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{
                        'message':$('#message').val()
                    }
                })
                // Ajaxリクエストが成功した時発動
                .done( (data) => {
                    $('.result').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                })
                // Ajaxリクエストが失敗した時発動
                .fail( (data) => {
                    $('.result').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                })
                // Ajaxリクエストが成功・失敗どちらでも発動
                .always( (data) => {

                });
            });
        });
  </script>
```

index_do.php

```php
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset= UTF-8');
    $message = h(isset($_POST["message"]));
    echo $message;//for confirm
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tb(mes) VALUES('$message')");
    $db->query("UPDATE `tb`");
    echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: `$message` の内容が 1 だからではないかと思います。

Comment: h() を使っていますが、CakePHPを使っているのでしょうか？独自のラッパー関数だとしたら、その内容次第で$messageに何が入るのかなんとも言えません。

Answer (score 1):

> isset($_POST["message"])

は、TRUE（存在）か FALSE（存在しない）を返すので　h()のなかで論理型が文字か数字に変換されて　”１”が表示されているのでは。

**isset**を使い $_POST["message"] が存在しているか、判断しているなら。

```
if(isset($_POST["message"])){
$message = h($_POST["message"]);
}else{
// $_POST["message"]が存在しない時の処理
}
```

とするのが良いと思います。
追伸、　XSS(クロスサイトスクリプティング)やSQLインジェクション に注意しましょう！

Comment: 質問にご回答いただきありがとうございます。 h()ですが、
function h($value){ return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
}
です。
記載漏れ失礼しました。 isset($_POST["message"])が論理型なのを見落としてました。
動作確認も問題なくinsert出来ました。
ありがとうございます。